# jquery todo list append li element to existing list

Tags: html, jquery

I am working on programming a todo list application with jquery, but there are some issuses/bugs I am facing. The first element is purposed to be set via HTML code and working like expected. My next step is to append another list element with a checkbox, input textfield, and a dropdown button if a user is clicking the "Neu" button. Like seen in the following picture.

[image]

The jquery code I am using to realise this is:

```js
$('ul.todo-list').append('<li>' +
            '<input type="checkbox"/>' +
            '<label>' +
            '<input [type="text"] placeholder="Insert your new task here"/>' +
            '</label>' +
            '<div class="arrow-btn"></div>' +
            '</li>');
```

After a user entered a random text and is clicking the enter button the new text is appearing under the first li element.

[image]

Here's the code snipped for this

```js
$('input').keypress(function (event) {
            if (((event.which || event.keyCode) == 13) && ($(this).val() != '')) {   //Werte bei keypress: ENTER und nicht leerem Textfeld abfragen und setzen
                var todoText = $(this).val();            //Werte aus <input type="text"/> Textfeld abfangen und in einer
                //neuen Variablen abspeichern

                // append new listelement, drop-down button, edit-duplicate-remove button
                $('ul.todo-list').append('<li>' +
                    '<input type="checkbox">' +
                    '<label>' +
                    '<span></span>' +
                    '<input type="text" id="inputValue" readonly/>' +
                    '</label>' +
                    '<div class="arrow-btn"></div>' +
                    '<ul class="item-menu-bar">' +
                    '<li class="edit-btn">Editieren</li>' +
                    '<li class="duplicate-btn">Duplizieren</li>' +
                    '<li class="remove-btn">L&ouml;schen</li>' +
                    '</ul>' +
                    '</li>');

                $('#inputValue').val(todoText);
```

Here starts my problem if a previews Item is being added to a list and a user wants to add another list item or element by clicking the "Neu" button my new todo list is looking like this. The value in picture number two "new item inserted" on list position two is being overwritten with a new value which normaly should be on list position 3 and the third list position is empty.

[image]

Comment: try my code it is somewhat same

Comment: You can instead of appending another `li` tag, remove the ID from the current input and add `readonly` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Id must be unique .. That means remove `id="inputValue"` because it keep repeating on every append .. And use the inline `value="'+todoText+'"` directly

Try this

```js
$('input').keypress(function (event) {
  if (((event.which || event.keyCode) == 13) && ($(this).val().trim() !== '')) {   //Werte bei keypress: ENTER und nicht leerem Textfeld abfragen und setzen
      var todoText = $(this).val();            //Werte aus <input type="text"/> Textfeld abfangen und in einer
      //neuen Variablen abspeichern

      // append new listelement, drop-down button, edit-duplicate-remove button
      $('ul.todo-list').append('<li>' +
          '<input type="checkbox">' +
          '<label>' +
          '<span></span>' +
          '<input type="text" value="'+todoText+'" readonly/>' +
          '</label>' +
          '<div class="arrow-btn"></div>' +
          '<ul class="item-menu-bar">' +
          '<li class="edit-btn">Editieren</li>' +
          '<li class="duplicate-btn">Duplizieren</li>' +
          '<li class="remove-btn">L&ouml;schen</li>' +
          '</ul>' +
          '</li>');
  }
});
```

Additional: Use `$(this).val().trim() !== ''` `trim` to avoid white-spaces